# How cmake find_package automatically find all the dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I have two static libraries: Foo and Bar. Bar is a high level component which encapsulates Foo. Both libraries have Config.cmake file.

After installing the libraries on the
system (so they are at /usr/local/lib) I'm using find_package to find Bar but the problem is that I also have to link target with Foo.

Is there any way that Foo can be found and linked automatically when Bar is linked?

[CMakeLists.txt for Foo library]:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

project(foo)

add_library(foo ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC "include")

set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR "include/foo/")
set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "lib/foo/")
set(INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake")

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

configure_package_config_file(FooConfig.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR}
  PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR})
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION ${INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR}/foo)
install(FILES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfigVersion.cmake
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR})
```

[CMakeLists.txt for Bar library]:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

project(bar)

add_library(bar ${SOURCES})    
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC "include")
target_link_libraries(bar PUBLIC foo)

set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR "include/bar/")
set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR "lib/bar/")
set(INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR "${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/cmake")

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

configure_package_config_file(BarConfig.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarConfig.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR}
  PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR)

write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

install(TARGETS bar DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR})
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION ${INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR}/bar)
install(FILES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarConfig.cmake
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarConfigVersion.cmake
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DESTINATION_DIR})
```

[User's CMakeLists.txt]:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

project(test)

find_package(bar CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS "/usr/local/lib/bar")
# I want the find_package above to find foo as well...

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${BAR_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_directories(test PRIVATE ${BAR_LIBRARY_DIR})

# ...and link it here automatically.
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC bar)
```

Comment: just set `FooConfig.cmake` to require the dependent libraries, the easiest way is to add an interface target that your consumers can link to

Comment: @michalis You are right - making bar a shared library solves the problem, but it also requires that the final application be delivered with the shared library, what I'm trying to avoid. In other words - I need to link statically.

Comment: Without setting `cmake_minimum_required`, the policy set is determined by the currently running CMake version which means that every single line in your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlexReinking thanks for the note! The original code does have cmake_minimum_required. The code in question is reduced to minimum - so only the parts that are related to the question are shown.

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required` is critically related to your question.

Comment: @AlexReinking I added cmake_minimum_required.

Comment: Is foo a dependency for bar? If not, I'd suggest that listing both explictly is the right choice. Otherwise you should simply use `find_package(foo)` and `target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)` in your list file - `find_dependency(foo)` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add cmake "interface library" to the BarConfig.cmake.in file:

```
  @PACKAGE_INIT@
  
  set_and_check(BAR_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@")
  set_and_check(BAR_LIBRARY_DIR "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@")

  check_required_components(bar)

  add_library(barlib INTERFACE)
  target_include_directories(barlib INTERFACE ${BAR_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_directories(barlib INTERFACE ${BAR_LIBRARY_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(barlib INTERFACE bar foo)
```

It creates a new library "barlib" which does not contain it's own code, but it has the libraries "bar" and "foo" as dependencies.

User's CMakeLists.txt now may look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

project(test)

find_package(bar CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS "/usr/local/lib/bar")

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE barlib)
```

The "test" binary here inherits all the dependencies of the "barlib" library.